# Buttons are stretching out of appBar component on screen size 400 px

Tags: css, reactjs, debugging, material-ui

I have an appBar component where I have 3 buttons inside it and they look ok in large screen sizes but start stretching out of the appBar at screen size 400 px

here's how they look on large screens:
[image: Photo of button components current behavior]

and then at 400 px this happens:

[image: Photo of undesired button behavior]

I tried deleting margins and paddings from it but nothing happened

Also, there are no elements causing extra margins so what could be the problem?

I made a sandbox for the problem here:https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-tdd-c1ocm?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend some sort of container.

```
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
. . . 
<Container>
 <Button className={classes.button}>English</Button>
 <Button className={classes.button}>Sign up</Button>
 <Button className={classes.button}>Login</Button>
</Container>
```

Seems to hold them together better. Do you think this would help?

Comment: I tried it and the buttons are not behaving as expected